# Conditional extremes

Tags: analysis

There is a given function $ f(x,y,z)=y(\cos x + \sin x)+z$ and $D={(x,y,z) | 0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi, 0 \leq y \leq 1, y^2 \leq z \leq 1}$, where I have to find all the maximums and minimums.

So, the first case was $int (D): 0<x<2 \pi,0<y<1,y^2<z<1$: since $f'_{x} =1 \neq 0$, there are no extremes in the interior.

The next step was, for example, straight line: $y=0,x=2 \pi, y^2 <z < 1: f(2 \pi,0,z)=z=g(z)$. Since $g'_{z}=1 \neq 0$, there are no extremes on this line.

Next step: also the straight line $z=1,y=1,0<x<2 \pi: f(x,1,1)=\cos x+\sin x+1$. Since $f'_{x}=-\sin x+ \cos x=0=f'_{y}=f'_{z}$, there is $x= \frac{\pi}{4}$, but, the quadratic forms were not with the constant sign, so, $(\frac{\pi}{4},1,1)$ is not maximum not minimum.

And so on.

When I tested all the possibilities, I got that there are no minimums not maximums.

I think I made some mistakes, can someone help me, or, tell me the extremes, so I can check the results?

Also, I have to find $f(D)$, it means I have to find the extremes first, right?

Thanks!

Comment: You *must* have made a mistake, because a continuous real function in a compact domain always has a maximum and a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Surfaces dropped out, corners (vertices) as well. 
You need to find stationary points for $f(x,y,y^2)$, $f(x,1,z)$ etc.
Corners are $(0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ ...

If I understand well, $D$ is a slice of a [parabolic cylinder](https://services.math.duke.edu/education/ccp/materials/mvcalc/surfaces/surf3.html).